# Is it possible to change the File-System of usb without loosing data and without taking backup?

Tags: filesystem

As the subject says, Can I change the file-system  of a usb (or say any drive) from it's current partition like :- ext4 to a different partition like:- ext2/fat/ext3/ntfs file-system without loosing the data in the drive and without taking backup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [File system  Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)

> On Linux, **ext2** can be **converted** to **ext3** (and converted **back**), and **ext3**
>   can be **converted** to **ext4** (but **not back**), and both ext3 and ext4
>   can be converted to btrfs, and converted back until the undo
>   information is deleted.These conversions are possible due to
>   using the same format for the file data itself, and relocating the
>   metadata into empty space, in some cases using sparse file support.

So it seems it is not Back-Convert-Compatible and Converting from ext4 to NTFS will require Formatting  , since they are totally different File-systems , also holds true for ext4 to Fatxx format .That means without data loss

**ext2** >> **ext3** possible

**ext3** >>**ext4** possible

**ext3** & **ext4** >> [btrfs possible](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Conversion_from_Ext3)

**ext4** >> **ntfs** not possible w/o Format

**ntfs** >> **extX** not possible w/o format

Please refer this [question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/256283/convert-windows-partition-to-linux-filesystem-without-losing-its-data) also.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that it depends on which filesystem you are "converting" from & to. There needs to be a specific program to convert it for you.

For example, a FAT16 or FAT32 filesystem on Windows can be converted to NTFS via the Windows ["convert"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214579) command. However, generally you cannot convert filesystems.

1 other option that may work though:
Ext4 filesystems can often (but not always) be mounted as ext3 or ext2.
Similarly, Ext3 filesystems can often be mounted as ext2.
e.g., on windows, I mount Ext3 & Ext4 filesystems using the ext2 driver [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/):